# Shell script sort a string

Tags: shell, unix, alphabet

i have a shell script variable etc "string"
i want to give this string as value of another variable,abc sorted 
like string=CDA
want to add ADC to a "ordered" variable

```
$string=CDA
$ordered=ADC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
> string=CDA
> s=$(grep -o . <<<"$string"|sort|tr -d "\n")
> echo "$s"
ACD
```